# log4j2 kafka appender over TLS/SSL

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, log4j2

I am trying to use the Apache Kafka appender for log4j2. I am able to publish my logs over Kafka successfully. The question I have is whether I can publish over TLS/SSL. I could not find documentation on how to configure a secure transport for the log4j2 kafka appender, or maybe I am lazy. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1) To set up SSL on the Kafka server, follow the steps outlined on docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html

2) On the Kafka server.properties, add the following

```
listeners=SSL://:9092
ssl.keystore.location=<Folder>/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=<password>
ssl.key.password=changeme
ssl.truststore.location=<Folder>/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<password>
ssl.client.auth=required
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
```

3) On the Kafka client (log4j2.xml file of the application that wants to send its logs over Kafka), add the following SSL properties under the Kafka appender configuration, as shown below

```
<Kafka name="Kafka"  topic="kafka.ssl.log4j2.test.topic">
    <!--JsonLayout complete="true" compact="false" eventEol="true" properties="true" locationInfo="true"/-->
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>[%-5level] [%t] [%C : %M : %F : %L] : %X : %m%n</Pattern> 
    </PatternLayout>
    <Property name="bootstrap.servers">localhost:9092</Property>
    <!--
    <Property name="security.protocol">SSL</Property>
    <Property name="ssl.truststore.location">truststore location of client</Property>
    <Property name="ssl.truststore.password">password</Property>
    <Property name="ssl.keystore.location">keystore location of client</Property>
    <Property name="ssl.keystore.password">password</Property>
    <Property name="ssl.key.password">key password</Property>
    -->
</Kafka>
```

4) That's it. You should now be able to send your logs to LogStash or any other application that has a Kafka plugin to pick up logs from Kafka.

Comment: Part of my answer has been auto-formatted so I don't see what I posted

Comment: Do you know how to put it in property file ?

Answer (score -1):

If needed the keystore/trustore type might be set like this.

```
<Property name="ssl.truststore.type">PKCS12</Property>
```