# Configure log4j.properties for Kafka appender, error when parsing property bootstrap.servers

Tags: scala, logging, apache-kafka, log4j, log4j2

I want to add a Kafka appender to the audit-hdfs log in a Cloudera cluster.

I have successfully configured a log4j2.xml file with a Kafka appender, I need to convert this log4j2.xml into a log4j2.properties file in order to be able to merge it with the HDFS log log4j2.properties file. I am unable to do this because when I launch my dummy process with log4j2.properties instead of XML, I get an error.

I have tried writing the properties file in several different ways, always resulting in problems with the bootstrap.servers property

This is my properties file

```
filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = ALL

appenders = console,kafka

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n

appender.kafka.type = Kafka
appender.kafka.name = kafka
appender.kafka.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.kafka.layout.pattern =%m%n
appender.kafka.property.type = Property
appender.kafka.property.bootstrap.servers = ip:port
appender.kafka.topic = cdh-audit-hdfs
```

Here the problem is in this line:
appender.kafka.property.bootstrap.servers = ip:port

I have tried the following, to no avail:

```
appender.kafka.property.bootstrap.servers = ip:port
```

```
appender.kafka.property.bootstrap\.servers = ip:port
```

```
appender.kafka.property.name = "bootstrap.servers"
appender.kafka.property.bootstrap.servers = ip:port
```

```
appender.kafka.property.key = "bootstrap.servers"
appender.kafka.property.value = ip:port
```

etc...

This is my dummy process:

```scala
package blabla

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager

object dummy extends App{
  val logger = LogManager.getLogger
  val record = "...c"
  while(true){
    logger.info(record)
    Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}
```

How do I need to configure my log4j2.properties in order to be able to define this property?

Im expecting this process to write the record in my Kafka topic but instead I get errors like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No type attribute provided for component bootstrap
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value.
```

Comment: Hello, did you find how to resolve your problem ?

Comment: No, sorry. Also I no longer have access to that project.

Comment: I founded a solution about this one. This kind of properties file is deprecated. Now we have to build our properties with a .xml file. The fact is "bootstrap.servers" is not interpreted as a full parameter but "servers" as a child of "bootstrap"

Answer (score 1):

try this solution, it works for me :

```
appender.kafka.property.type=Property
appender.kafka.property.name=bootstrap.servers
appender.kafka.property.value=host:port
```

Comment: This is the only one property, do you know how to set multiple of them, for example when ssl is needed ? In xml it is simple and example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062762/log4j2-kafka-appender-over-tls-ssl  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
appender.kafka.property1.type=property
appender.kafka.property1.name=bootstrap.servers
appender.kafka.property1.value=ip:port
appender.kafka.property2.type=property
appender.kafka.property2.name=security.protocol
appender.kafka.property2.value=SASL_PLAINTEXT
appender.kafka.property3.type=property
appender.kafka.property3.name=sasl.mechanism
appender.kafka.property3.value=PLAIN
appender.kafka.property4.type=property
appender.kafka.property4.name=sasl.jaas.configappender.kafka.property4.value=`org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"xxxx\" password=\"xxxx\";`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).